# How to add gulp task to angular cli build

Tags: angular, deployment, gulp, angular-cli, bundling-and-minification

I'm switching my deployment tool for an Angular 4 project to [angular/cli](https://cli.angular.io). The command `ng build` will put the resulting bundles in a `dist` folder by default.

I need to figure out how to add my custom task to this process. Specifically, I have a lot of `.svg` files that I need to bundle and minify into a `sprite.defs.svg` file, and place the result in `dist/assets/svg/`.  With my previous deployment toolchain, I used `gulp` with the [`gulp-svg-sprite` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprite).  Here was my bundling step:

```
const svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite');

gulp.src('**/*.svg')
  .pipe(svgSprite({
    mode: {
      defs: {
        dest:'.',
        sprite:"sprite.defs.svg"
      }
    }
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/svg'));
```

Is there a simple way to integrate something like this into angular/cli's `ng build`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say, you manually run this gulp task as

```
gulp processSVG
```

In the scripts section of package.json, define a command like this:

```
"prebuild": "gulp processSVG"
```

npm script is smart enough to run the command with the "pre" prefix before the command with the same name, but without this prefix. Now, run the following command:

```
npm run build
```

This command will run the prebuild command first and then the build command.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a mirror convention for running something after an npm script? eg: `"postbuild": "..."`.  I actually need my task to run after the build... just tested and it's exactly that. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, postbuild will run the command right after the build. The pre and post work with any command.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to accomplish this as well
set your ngbuild options and then add **" && gulp "** and your gulp task like follows:

```
"scripts":{
    "buildDev": "ng build --deleteOutputPath=true --sourceMap=true && gulp your-task"
}
```

I can confirm that @Yakov Fain's solution still works with angular 7 as well as mine